# Accessing OSGI bundles from Android app

Tags: android, osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I'm running OSGI (Apache Felix) embedded in my Android app. Furthermore I'm able to install, register and start a service providing and a service consuming bundle. The service consuming bundle consumes the service provided by the service providing bundle as intended.
Now I would like my app to communicate with the bundles, i.e. provide method parameters to the bundles or receive processing results from there.

Unfortunately when trying to access a bundle directly from my app I either receive `ClassCastException`s for the same type due to different class loaders involved or a `NoClassDefFoundException`.

**START Update**

Central to my app is a worker service w which starts another service f solely responsible for managing OSGI matters. The bundles to be run within f are only available as *.jar files all of them exporting their own interface. From within w I'm able to get hold of a ServiceTracker object tracking the instance of the object implementing the bundle interface via

`ServiceTracker serviceTracker = new ServiceTracker(context,"my.bundle.BundleInterface", null);`.

I can now extract the actual service object via
`Object serviceObject = serviceTracker.getService();` from outside of any bundle just within the code of w.

Now calling `BundleInterface interfaceObject = (BundleInterface) serviceObject;` results in a `NoClassDefFoundException`.

I have already added the bundles' jar files to the build path for the code to compile at all.

How can I access my `serviceObject`?
I guess this is a matter of classloading but how do I ensure that the class is loaded by the same classloaders? Do I have to add any entries to the felix config properties file?

**END Update**

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer your question. I would be great to have more details ;-) In which cases, do the exceptions occur? Could you give me some snippets to have a look at?

I guess that the `ClassCastException` could come from the fact that a class is loaded by two different class loaders. Both service consumer and provider need to share the class from a same bundle. If this is the service interface, a good practice consists in defining it in a share bundle that contains the API of your bundle (all service interfaces, ...)

There are some case where the service implementation can't know in advance the classes they will use (for example, an ORM doesn't know the model classes in advance). In such cases, the TCCL (Thread Context Class Loader) can be very useful.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thanks for your reply - you are right - seems to be a classloader problem but although I'm sure i basically understand what is the problem I'm unfortunately unsure of what the actual solution has to look like.